# Getting error : Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Socket closed

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am working on client-server chat program.

I have the two programs as follows:

client.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

class client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        // ServerSocket SerSock = new ServerSocket(8090);

        Socket cliSock = new Socket("localhost",8090);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    cliSock.getInputStream()));

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(
                                    cliSock.getOutputStream()));
        // out.write("some data".getBytes());


        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String message="";
        message = in.readLine();

        System.out.println(message);

        // while((message = in.readLine()) != "bye")
        // {
        //  System.out.println(message);
        //  System.out.println("I am in while in client");

        //  out.write(scan.nextLine());
        // }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        cliSock.close();
        // SerSock.close();

    }
}
```

server.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

class server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        ServerSocket SerSock = new ServerSocket(8090);

        System.out.println("Waiting for client...");

        Socket cliSock = SerSock.accept();

        // open();

        // while ( !cliSock.isConnected())
        // {

        // }

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                    cliSock.getInputStream()));

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(
                                    cliSock.getOutputStream()));

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        String message = "Hello client";
        System.out.println(message);
        out.write(message);

        // while((message = in.readLine()) != "bye")
        // {

        //  System.out.println("I am in while in server");

        //  System.out.println(message);
        //  message = scan.nextLine();

        //  out.write(message);
        // }
        in.close();
        out.close();


        cliSock.close();
        SerSock.close();

    }
}
```

Basically, I wanted to make a chat server program so that both can chat until they get bye message. I am unable to implement the program. The error is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:121)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implClose(StreamEncoder.java:316)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.close(StreamEncoder.java:149)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.close(OutputStreamWriter.java:233)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.close(BufferedWriter.java:266)
    at server.main(server.java:44)
```

I am novice in java. Please help me in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to chat back and forth, stop closing your Input and Output Streams. Also, closing either stream on a Socket is equivalent to closing the Socket itself.

You should create a loop to keep reading new data from your Sockets

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(so.getInputStream());

while(true) {
  String line = br.readLine();
  ...
}
```

Comment: I am still getting null at client side.

Comment: I commented a few lines from my code, by which I intended to chat back and forth..Is that right..

Answer (score 0):

If you are uncertain how to correctly use a class, or if an instance is behaving in a way you do not understand, then your first recourse should be to read [the class's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html).

If you had done so in this case, then you would have found that closing either the input stream or the output stream of a `Socket` closes the whole `Socket`.  Your exception is being thrown when class `server` attempts to close a `Socket`s output stream after already closing its input stream.  Note also that `Socket.close()` will close both streams, so you could just use that (only).